# Dynamically created "method_missing" containing a closure and supporting a passed block

Tags: ruby

I would like to dynamically create method_missing on an object, while still allowing it to accept blocks.  At the same time, I need to use a closure in the dynamically created method_missing.  Here's the problem:

1. To create the closure, I need to use `define_singleton_method` to create `method_missing`, passing it a block to create the closure.
2. Blocks cannot themselves accept blocks, so the newly created `method_missing` can't accept a block.

Simple demo, for clarification only (ie, I care about solving the general case, not this specific problem):

```
close_over_me = "99"
o = Object.new
o.define_singleton_method(:method_missing) do |*all_args|
  meth, *args = all_args
  "The args passed to #{meth}: #{args}. Special code: #{close_over_me}"
end

p o.hi(42) #=> "The args passed to hi: [42]. Special code: 99"
```

Now let's say I wanted to pass in a block, which changed the special code somehow, eg, by doubling it.  That is, I'd like to write:

```
p o.hi(42) {|x| 2*x}
```

Keep in mind I want to achieve all of the following:

1. It will work with any method name.
2. `method_missing` must create a closure when it's dynamically defined.  Hence cannot do `def o.method_missing...`
3. It must work with any number of arguments, and we don't know the number of arguments in advance.  The arguments could be of any type.

Is there any metaprogramming magic that can achieve all these at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `define_method` family of methods, the parameter list of the block passed to `define_method` becomes the parameter list of the method defined by `define_method`, so all you need to do to take a block parameter is to add a block parameter to the block's parameter list:

```
close_over_me = "99"
o = Object.new
o.define_singleton_method(:method_missing) do |meth, *args, &blk|
  blk ||= -> x { x }
  "The args passed to #{meth}: #{args}. Special code: #{blk.(close_over_me)}"
end

p o.hi(42) {|x| x*2 }  #=> "The args passed to hi: [42]. Special code: 9999"
```

Comment: Thanks.  In general, if the final argument is prepended with `&`, does ruby always interpret it as an optional block?

Comment: Hmmm... just playing around with this, and it seems it's not that simple.  Eg, `block_given?` doesn't work.  Yet it doesn't give an incorrect number of args error when you leave the block out.  Can you elaborate on what exactly is going on?

Comment: The unary prefix ampersand operator/sigil means two dual things depending on where it is used. It can only be used in argument lists and parameter lists. In an argument list, it means "unroll a `Proc` into a block as if you had passed the literal block as an argument (and if the object *isn't* a `Proc`, call `to_proc` to convert it to one)". This allows you to, for example say something like `some_enum.each(&method(:puts))` to print out all elements of an `Enumerable` object (since `Method` implements `to_proc`) or `some_enum.map(&:to_s)` (because `Symbol` implements `to_proc` as well). …

Comment: … When used in a *parameter list*, it means the dual: package up o block into a `Proc` object, so that it can be stored in variables, passed to other methods, manipulated as an object, and so on. If no block is passed, the parameter will be bound to `nil`. Remember, blocks aren't objects, and they are anonymous. The only things you can do is `yield` to them, and ask if there is one (`block_given?`). However, both of these refer to the lexically enclosing method definition (i.e. the closest `def` keyword). So, in your case, although you don't want to store the block nor pass it on, you have …

Comment: … to use an explicit block argument, since you are not within a method definition but rather within a block literal. (The fact that the block happens to be passed to a method which will ultimately result in a method being defined, is irrelevant from the perspective of inside the block. A block literal is a block literal, not a method definition, if you were to use `yield` or `block_given?` inside of it, it would refer to the lexically enclosing method definition, and in this case, there simply is none.)

Comment: I could explicitly check whether or not `blk` is `nil` (or whether it is truthy, since it can only be `nil`, i.e. falsy or a `Proc` object, i.e. truthy – this latter one is what I'm implicitly doing in line 4), but in this case, I simply bind it to the identity function if it is unbound using the `||=` conditional compound assignment operator. Unfortunately, it's not possible to use default arguments syntax for this.

Comment: you are my favorite SO poster.  happy new year jörg!

Answer (score 0):

Here is modified code - you can expect a `block` along with `all_args`.
Block presence has to be validated before issuing a call to it.

Also note that since `close_over_me` is a string, so doubling it by multiplying by 2 results in `"9999"`.

```
close_over_me = "99"
o = Object.new
o.define_singleton_method(:method_missing) do |*all_args, &block|
  meth, *args = all_args
  "The args passed to #{meth}: #{args}. Special code: #{block ? block.call(close_over_me) : close_over_me}"
end

p o.hi(42) {|x| x * 2}
#=> "The args passed to hi: [42]. Special code: 9999"
p o.hi(42)
#=> "The args passed to hi: [42]. Special code: 99"
```

Answer (score 0):

Though it is definitely possible:

```
close_over_me = "99"
o = Object.new
o.define_singleton_method(:method_missing) do |*all_args, &cb|
  meth, *args = all_args
  yielded = cb.call(13) if cb
  "Args #{meth}: #{args}. Code: #{close_over_me}. Yielded: #{yielded}."
end

p o.hi(42)
#=> "The args passed to hi: [42]. Special code: 99. Block yielded:."
p o.hi(42) { |x| 2 * x }
#=> "The args passed to hi: [42]. Special code: 99, Block yielded: 26."
```

I can not get *how it is supposed to **work** with any amount of arguments*, since inside the singleton we should call it explicitly.

It seems to me you are misdesigning things.

Comment: your assumption that we call it explicitly is incorrect.  imagine we are copying some other method_missing to this object, while perhaps inserting some logging code before calling it.  it might take any number of arguments, and might or might not have a block

Comment: Ah, so, I think the fifth line of the code above should be modified to `yielded = cb.call(*args) if cb`, because _from inside block_ within `define_singleton_method`, we _are to call it explicitly_, via `cb.call`.